# How to match the whole String using String Handling functions

Tags: arrays, string

I read the data from the table and output for that comes as "6428958 12/01/2021 02:09:25 PM Open Solving **CANCEL**" from this I need the last value so using split function and comparing the values from my map. My map look like 'PTP',
'CANCEL',
'NY SURRENDERS',
'SURRENDERS/ LOANS-ANA',
'OVERLOAN REPORT',
'SURRENDERS/LOANS-COR',
'POLICY CONVERSION',
'A&H CANCELLATIONS',
'OWNERSHIP CHANGES'

If my string matches with any last word then I should proceed or else i should raise the exception.
But if the last word is CANCEL FOR PROCESSING, as it is moving further but it should raise exception.
As per my map It need to accept only Cancel but also accepting other words which contain CANCEL.

Can you help me how to restrict that

Comment: Please post more details. You haven't even said anything about whichever the programming language you're using....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with an if / else if cascade groing from the most specific to least
Then replace the space with some kind of token : say ##

```js
if (theString.contains('CANCEL FOR PROCESSING')) {
  // Proceed some stuff
  theString.replace('CANCEL FOR PROCESSING', 'CANCEL##FOR##PROCESSING')
} else if (theString.contains('CANCEL OTHER STUFF')) {
  theString.replace('CANCEL OTHER STUFF', 'CANCEL##OTHER##STUFF')
}
```

Then you inside your so called "map" which in fact is an array you can process a switch back tokens

```js
for (elem of yourSplitArray) {
   elem = elemn.replace('##', ' ')
}
```

Comment: but when we have CANCEL FOR PROCESSING or CANCEL OTHER STUFF it is not identifying as CANCEL FOR PROCESSING. it is identifying as only Cancel. because after getting this whole string "6428958 12/01/2021 02:09:25 PM Open Solving CANCEL" from the table in order to get the final column value, I am splitting wrt space. So it is treating CANCEL and CANCEL FOR PROCESSING in same way.